# Passing the name of radio button in maya/python

Tags: python, maya

How do you get the label/value of a radioButton in python? Can't find any good info on such a simple thing.

```
#radioButtons
cmds.radioButton(l="Circle", select=True)
cmds.radioButton(l='Triangle')
cmds.radioButton(l='Square' )
```

When i try use a value of a selected radioButton i can't because I keep getting "radioButton539" and it changes every time i run the code.

Comment: If, instead of `l="your label"...`, you do `label="your label"`, does it work?

Comment: No, tried that. I'm really confused. This going by the docs it should work. There's no mention of any other way of adding a value to the radioButtons. I must be missing something very small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, without any name, maya automatically names the UI elements. To name the UI element you usually do it with the first argument:

```
theName = "MyRadioButtonName"
cmds.radioButton(theName, l="Circle", select=True)
```

But you have to be careful because if the UI element aready exists, you will get another name. The best way is to use the name the way it is returned from the command:

```
theName = "MyRadioButtonName"
theButton = cmds.radioButton(theName, l="Circle", select=True)
...
label = cmds.radioButton(theButton, q=True, l=True)
```

Comment: This was all I needed. I could not find that anywhere. All i wanted was to have a name sent when a submit button is pressed. Then I can run a conditional statement to set variables based on which radioButton is selected. Thanks